# Define a DTD ATTLIST to allow a new attribute to be without a value?

Tags: xml, dtd, html4

I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"

    [
        <!ATTLIST a extra-attr CDATA #IMPLIED>
    ]>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a extra-attr>hola</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I need is:

1. The attribute value  present: `<a extra-attr="value"></a>` should be valid
2. The attribute value not present: `<a extra-attr></a>` **valid as well**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said [here](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200107/post61430.html):

> A bareword attribute is a violation of the XML spec.  The XHTML spec
>   says that the best way around such cases where HTML has a bareword
>   attribute (selected, checked, multiple, etc.) is to use
>   selected="selected", checked="checked", and so on.  An SGML HTML
>   parser (web browser) will ignore the value it's given, and an XML
>   XHTML parser (good web browser) will acknowledge the value, and ignore
>   it.  A file with selected="selected" is valid XHTML, according to the
>   W3C's validation program.